# fabric.js cannot get the text aligned witht the textAlign

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I cannot get the textAlign working in fabric.js The fontSize, fontBackground work properly, but not textAlign. Am I missing something?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

$('button.addText').click(function() {
  var text = new fabric.Text($(this).siblings().val(), {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 40
  });
  canvas.add(text);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var align = ["left", "center", "right" , "justify"];
var el = document.getElementById('res');
var txt = 'FabricJS \n is \nAwsome';

var text = new fabric.Text(txt, {
    textAlign: 'left', //"left", "center", "right" or "justify".
    width:450,
    fontSize: 40
  });
canvas.add(text);
changeAlign();

function changeAlign(){
 var val = align[Math.floor(Math.random() * align.length)];
 text.set('textAlign',val);
 el.innerHTML = 'Text Alignment : ' +val;
 canvas.setActiveObject(text);
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border : 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas><br>
<button onclick='changeAlign()'>Change align</button><p id='res'></p>
```

@AndreaBogazzi He is right. In Text, box depends on the width of first line, if you want then it will work for multi line texts . Check Snippet.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Ya chenged to Text. Never thought of this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I didn't realize that this works with 1. mulriple line tekst and 2. it is bounded to the textBox. is there a way then to set the textBox width to the width of canvas? or otherwise align the textBoxrelatively to the canvas?

Comment: @AleksandraChuprova you can set canvas width to text box, if it is multi line then alignment will work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main point is that if the text is one line only, fabric will size the text bounding box to the necessary length and there will not be any alignment to do.

If the text is multiline the alignment should work.

The alignment is INSIDE the box and is not the direction where the box grows when the text grows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the fact taht it works on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of the object. If you have for example `IText` or `Text` the alignment will work only in the area of the canvas itself.

For example if you want to align an `IText` type on the center of the canvas you would use:

```
canvas.getActiveObject().centerV();
canvas.getActiveObject().setCoords(); 
canvas.renderAll();
```

If you want to center the text itself it would apply only to **Textbox** type, you would then be able to use:

```
canvas.getActiveObject().textAlign = "center";
```